# how to convert image into base64 string?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

hello I am trying to make simple application in ionic using camera or select file from gallery or file system and send to / or upload to a server.
I found one plugin which capture one image and send **base64** string 
here is plugin 
http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/camera/
using this I am able to get base64 string

```
$cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function(imageData) {
      var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
      image.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
    }, function(err) {
      // error
    });
```

that base64 string I used to send to server

But my problem is that when I use this plugin image gallary plugin

http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/imagePicker/
it send me only image url (where is in memory) .can we get **base64** string after selecting the image from image picker.

```
$cordovaImagePicker.getPictures(options)
    .then(function (results) {
      for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        console.log('Image URI: ' + results[i]);
      }
    }, function(error) {
      // error getting photos
    });
```

In other words when I using camera I am getting base64 string as shown above.But when I use image picker plugin I am getting image url.can I get base64 string .so that I am able to send or upload on server .
how to convert image url to base64 string ?

Comment: Kindly see below post 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150289/how-to-convert-image-into-base64-string-using-javascript can help you out ?

Comment: yes it working ,...thanks for help ..:)

Comment: ok great ..am posting it as answer..please accept it as answer @user944513

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this 100% working code. First you have to Download `ngCordova.min.js` file and include it in your `index.html` file. Follow this code.

```js
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])

.controller('DashCtrl', function($scope,$cordovaCamera) {
 $scope.imgUrl;
 $scope.dataImg;
 $scope.tackPicture = function(){
   var options = {
      quality: 50,
      destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
      sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
      allowEdit: true,
      encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
      targetWidth: 100,
      targetHeight: 100,
      popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
      saveToPhotoAlbum: false,
   correctOrientation:true
    };
  $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function(imageData) {
      //var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
   $scope.dataImg = imageData; // <--- this is your Base64 string 
      $scope.imgUrl = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
    }, function(err) {
      // error
    });
 }
})

.controller('ChatsCtrl', function($scope, Chats) {
  // With the new view caching in Ionic, Controllers are only called
  // when they are recreated or on app start, instead of every page change.
  // To listen for when this page is active (for example, to refresh data),
  // listen for the $ionicView.enter event:
  //
  //$scope.$on('$ionicView.enter', function(e) {
  //});

  $scope.chats = Chats.all();
  $scope.remove = function(chat) {
    Chats.remove(chat);
  };
})

.controller('ChatDetailCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, Chats) {
  $scope.chat = Chats.get($stateParams.chatId);
})

.controller('AccountCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.settings = {
    enableFriends: true
  };
});
```

```html
<ion-view view-title="Dashboard">
  <ion-content class="padding">
   <button class="button icon-left ion-ios-camera button-block button-positive" ng-click="tackPicture()">
     OPEN CAMERA
   </button>
     <div class="item item-avatar">
    <img ng-src="{{ imgUrl }}">
   
    <p>{{ dataImg }}</p>
  </div>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Comment: Keep in mind that using Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL will generate a memory load which in many cases is going to trigger a "bug" where the app is restarted after the user finished taking/selecting a picture

Answer (score 2):

To convert image to base64 you can use HTML5 canvans as mention in

[How to convert image into base64 string using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150289/how-to-convert-image-into-base64-string-using-javascript)

Please refer above question

Use this code

```
/**
 * Convert an image 
 * to a base64 url
 * @param  {String}   url         
 * @param  {Function} callback    
 * @param  {String}   [outputFormat=image/png]           
 */
function convertImgToBase64URL(url, callback, outputFormat){
    var img = new Image();
    img.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous';
    img.onload = function(){
        var canvas = document.createElement('CANVAS'),
        ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'), dataURL;
        canvas.height = this.height;
        canvas.width = this.width;
        ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
        dataURL = canvas.toDataURL(outputFormat);
        callback(dataURL);
        canvas = null; 
    };
    img.src = url;
}
```